# Angular replacing character from variable in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular so it's probably something easy I'm struggling with.

Here's the JSON with the data:

```
[
     {
        "date"      : "2016-02-12T20:30:00",
        "duration"  : 60,
        "supervisor": {
            "name"           : "Anna",
            "surname"        : "Nowak",
            "supervision_fee": "140.00"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm feeding this into a `select` element like this:

```
<select name="meetingSelect" 
    ng-model="meeting.active" 
    ng-options="meeting.id as meeting.date|date:'dd.MM.yy' + ' '+ meeting.supervisor.name + ' '+meeting.supervisor.surname for meeting in scheduledMeetings" 
    ng-change="" class="form-control">
</select>
```

What I get however in my HTML code is the following: 
`12.02.16 AnnPM No6PMK`

Seems that Angular must be escaping (?) some characters (like out of 'a' we get 'PM')...

Why is this happening and what to do about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks that the name you're printing is part of the date format. Try using parenthesis in `ng-options`.

```
ng-options="meeting.id as (meeting.date|date:'dd.MM.yy') + ' '+ meeting.supervisor.name + ' '+meeting.supervisor.surname for meeting in scheduledMeetings"
```

Your format was interpreted as `meeting.date|date:'dd.MM.yy Anna Nowak'` where some characters like `a` have [special meaning](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is being interpreted as:

```
meeting.date|date:(
   'dd.MM.yy' + ' '+ meeting.supervisor.name + ' '+meeting.supervisor.surname)
```

so:

```
meeting.date|date:'dd.MM.yy Anna Nowak'
```

which is a very strange format string for a date.